# remove PackageSource from PSModule in Win 10 PackageManager

Tags: windows-10, powershell

So i started using the powershell PackageManager in Win10 today and the first command i found to install chocolatey was

```
Register-PackageSource -Name chocolatey -Location http://chocolatey.org/api/v2 -Provider PSModule -Trusted -Verbose
```

Sound's good. Finds packages, but upon trying to install, it says:

```
The module 'vlc' cannot be installed or updated because it is not a properly-formed module.
```

Then I found

```
Get-PackageProvider Chocolatey -Force
```

which installs it as a separat provider and seems to work. Now when trying to install I have to specify the provider.

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-PackageSource
Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  IsRegistered IsValidated  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  ------------ -----------  --------
chocolatey                       Chocolatey       False      True         False        http://choc
PSGallery                        PSModule         False      True         False        https://www
chocolatey                       PSModule         True       True         False        http://choc
```

How can i delete the PSModule source for chocolatey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Unregister-PackageSource](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn890707.aspx)

```
Unregister-PackageSource -n chocolatey
```